# AccessViolationException when calling an extern method directly

Tags: c#, c++, rest, exception, access-violation

I have a nuget formed from a C++ project - inside that nuget I have an extern method `GetBytes` inside of a static class FileAccess.cs that I call in another project's (C#) REST service call to retrieve some data. Whenever I call this `GetBytes` `extern` method from my C# REST service I get an `AccessViolationException` for some reason. The method takes in a two strings and several int values and returns an `IntPtr`.

I'm confused because I have a similar call that does not result in a violation. The key difference is that this version does not call the extern method directly. Instead, it calls a C# DataGroup class (which is part of the nuget) which contains a function that calls the extern method. The DataGroup class method returns a `byte[,]`, but only after it calls the extern method and marshals the data.

// Version resulting in AccessViolation:

1. REST call to extern method as `IntPtr` (`IntPtr ptr = FileAccess.getBytes(...);`
2. extern method returns an `IntPtr`
3. `AccessViolationException` occurs

// Working version with extra class:

1. REST call to data group method that returns a `byte[,]`. (e.g. `dataGroupInstance.getDataGroupBytes();`
2. extern method is called inside method `getDataGroupBytes`
3. extern method returns an `IntPtr`
4. method `getDataGroupBytes` marshals the data from `IntPtr` and returns a `byte[,]`
5. no error

Basically, why is calling the extern method directly resulting in an `AccessViolationException`?

Comment: If your `FileAccess.getBytes(...);` method takes varargs, make sure to set `CallingConvention.Cdecl` on the PInvoke signature.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was a result of my parameters - my C++ functions used `std::string` when I should have been using `const char*`. I replaced all instances of `std::string` (where they were used as parameters) with `const char*` and I no longer received the exception.